# Object detection using emgu cv CvInvoke.cvHoughCircles

Tags: c#, emgucv

I want to detect objects using `cvHoughCircles` method in visual c#.If anyone knows how to do this please help me.

**Edit Details:**

I searched in the Internet there is examples using `gray.HoughCircles` method.
 this is my code.

```
 Image<Bgr, Byte> image = capture.QueryFrame();
 MCvScalar hsv_min = new MCvScalar(150, 84, 130, 0);
 MCvScalar hsv_max = new MCvScalar(358, 256, 255, 0);
 IntPtr hsv_frame = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new System.Drawing.Size(640,         480),IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
 IntPtr thresholded = CvInvoke.cvCreateImage(new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);


 CvInvoke.cvCvtColor(image, hsv_frame, COLOR_CONVERSION.CV_BGR2HSV);
 CvInvoke.cvInRangeS(hsv_frame, hsv_min, hsv_max, thresholded);

 IntPtr storage = CvInvoke.cvCreateMemStorage(0);
  CvInvoke.cvSmooth(thresholded, thresholded, SMOOTH_TYPE.CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9, 0, 0);

IntPtr circles= CvInvoke.cvHoughCircles(thresholded,   storage,HOUGH_TYPE.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT , 2, 4, 100, 50, 10, 400);
```

In the following link there is code.But it is in pythen.So what I'm doing is trying to convert it into visual c#.

http://www.lirtex.com/robotics/fast-object-tracking-robot-computer-vision/#comment-847

I want to take all detected circles in to for loop and then draw circle to corresponding objects as in pythen code.

I tried to use foreach loop but there is error,

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.IntPtr' because 'System.IntPtr' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Is there any method to avoid this error.

Comment: Maybe you should read some articles on the issue. Try a bit yourself. Test a few code samples. Then come back when you find further, more specific issues. =)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this tutorial?
[Shape (Triangle, Rectangle, Circle, Line) Detection in CSharp](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp)

This contains good tutorial which may be help you.

Comment: I think he specifically wants to use the CvInvoke class